Re-apply conditional formatting after filter
In Google Sheets I have one column of data that is confiditionally formatted to rank the data and colour code it depending on where it sits in the percentile. I achieve this by using the following
=AND(I2:I<>"",(COUNT(I$2:I)- RANK(I2,I$2:I))/COUNT(I$2:I) >=0.90)
=AND(I2:I<>"",(COUNT(I$2:I)- RANK(I2,I$2:I))/COUNT(I$2:I) >=0.75)
=AND(I2:I<>"",(COUNT(I$2:I)- RANK(I2,I$2:I))/COUNT(I$2:I) >=0.11)
=AND(I2:I<>"",(COUNT(I$2:I)- RANK(I2,I$2:I))/COUNT(I$2:I) <=0.10) 

I would then like to apply a fitler on a different column to remove certain rows. This however removes the matching rankings and does not recalculate the ranking based on what is now visible after applying the filter.
Is there a way to have the conditional formatting re-apply to only the visible data that will change depending on the filter drop down selected ?
here is a demo sheet, as you can see APAC is blue to represent the top 90th percentile but if I remove APAC via the filter the top percentile disappears, I want it to recalculate based on the visible fields.

It will be helpful if you can provide a sample sheet with sample data and desired output.

Example sheet added


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(x,$B$2:$B,Σ,filter(x,x<>"",map(x,lambda(Λ,subtotal(103,Λ)))),and($B2<>"",(count(Σ)-rank($B2,Σ))/count(Σ)>=0.9))



Change all the 4 rules accordingly


Alternative via a Helper Column
=vstack("HELPER_",
 map(B2:B,lambda(Γ,if(Γ="",,let(x,B2:B,Σ,filter(x,x<>"",map(x,lambda(Λ,subtotal(103,Λ)))),(count(Σ)-rank(Γ,Σ))/count(Σ))))))




WOW ... I am not even going to pretend I understand that but thank you very much, that works as I need.

Unfortunaltey on a large sheet, applying this to many columns is causing out of memory errors

Updated another method where you create a helper column with a single formula in top cell & then base your conditional formatting on this column values
